Bachelier implied volatilities in the Libor market model
There are various papers on how to derive a Black76 implied volatlity for a given specification of a Libor market model (especially for deterministic but time dependent volatility of forward rates and more envolved for the case of a stochastic volatility scaling).
My setting is the following:
$$
dF_k(t)/(F_k(t)+\delta) = drift + v_t \sigma(t) dW_t
$$
where $\delta$ is a displacement parameter, $\sigma(t)$ is deterministic and $v_t$ is the instantaneous volatility scaling that follows a CIR-process.
Are there any papers on a (direct not via Black76) derivation of Bachelier/normal vols for caps or even for swaptions? Or would it be best to first consider Black76 vols and then approximate normal vols?
